# How do I plot such stacked bar chart from pandas dataframe? I want 2 column names ("A" and "B") as X axis

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot

My pandas dataframe is read from below spreadsheet. I want "A" and "B" on the X axis.

print(df) gives:

```
         A       B
X
X1  0.9490  0.9637
X2  0.0213  0.0148
X3  0.0233  0.0177
X4  0.0064  0.0038
```

Thanks!

[image: example chart]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Oftentimes, plotting requires putting the dataframe into a particular shape.
- [Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the dataframe and plot it with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'A': {'X1': 0.949, 'X2': 0.0213, 'X3': 0.0233, 'X4': 0.0064},
        'B': {'X1': 0.9637, 'X2': 0.0148, 'X3': 0.0177, 'X4': 0.0038}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         A       B
X1  0.9490  0.9637
X2  0.0213  0.0148
X3  0.0233  0.0177
X4  0.0064  0.0038

# Transpose and plot
df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]